# check my Calendar date parameter is current date

Tags: java, date

I just wanted to find date parameter is current date (yyyy-MM-dd) without using simpledateformater or any date to string convertion and then find is equals.

`specifiedDate=2012-12-20`
`currentDate=2012-12-21`

`specifiedDate == currentDate`

to be simple i dont want time (i.e HH:mm:S) not to be included while validating

i have tried something like

```
public boolean isCurrentDate(Calendar date){
 Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
 if (currentDate.getDate()==(date.getTime().getDate()) 
            && currentDate.getMonth()==(date.getTime().getMonth())  
            && currentDate.getYear()==(date.getTime().getYear()) )
 {
  return true;
 }

 return false;
}
```

please suggest a better way or if any libraries already available for this !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using calendar

```
public static boolean isSameDay(Calendar cal1, Calendar cal2) {
            if (cal1 == null || cal2 == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The dates must not be null");
            }
            return (cal1.get(Calendar.ERA) == cal2.get(Calendar.ERA) &&
                    cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
                    cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
        }



public static boolean isToday(Calendar cal) {
        return isSameDay(cal, Calendar.getInstance());
    }
```

If you are using Date

```
public static boolean isSameDay(Date date1, Date date2) {
        if (date1 == null || date2 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The dates must not be null");
        }
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(date1);
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.setTime(date2);
        return isSameDay(cal1, cal2);
    }

 public static boolean isToday(Date date) {
        return isSameDay(date, Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you want to do only

**1) Using strings**

```
String s1 = new String("2012-01-27");
String s2 = new String("2011-01-28");
System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s2));
```

The result will be TRUE if s1 is "bigger" than s2 in lexicographical way and it's what you need. To get more info read javadoc for compareTo() method.

**2) Using Joda Time**

Using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) lib you can acheive as below

```
DateTime first = ...;
DateTime second = ...;

LocalDate firstDate = first.toLocalDate();
LocalDate secondDate = second.toLocalDate();

return firstDate.compareTo(secondDate);
```

I prefer second option

Comment: Thanks. But, i dont want to do any string comparison.

Comment: if i use your second option i have to convert my Calendar instance to LocalDate (Joda) ?

Comment: DateTime first = DateTimeFormatter.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2012-12-21");

Comment: @prabhu Check out my edits. As you requested without using simpledateformater or any date to string conversion!!

Comment: You don't want to do String comparison, you don't want simpledateformatter. I don't have further solution without that.

Answer (score 2):

What about setting time fields to 0 before comparing

```
currentDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);  
currentDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);  
currentDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  
currentDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last line `&& currentDate.getYear()==(date.getMonth()) )` appears to be comparing the year and month not the year and year. Could this be your issue?

Comment: @prabhu ok, just checking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`currentDate.set(Calendar.DATE, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

## Time Zone

The example code in your question ignores the crucial issue of time zone. The date, that is the beginning and ending points of a day, is defined by a time zone.

Both java.util.Calendar and java.util.Date have no time zone assigned. They represent a date and a time in UTC/GMT.

So you need to apply a desired time zone, relevant to the context of your app & data. That means you need a decent date-time library. Something other than java.util.Date/Calendar, java.text.SimpleDateFormat and their sibling classes, as they are notoriously troublesome. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) bundled with Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310).

Note the use of the method `withTimeAtStartOfDay`. That gets the first moment of the day. That is usually the time 00:00:00 but not always. Daylight Saving Time (DST) or other anomalies may produce a different time. That method smartly handles such issues.

## Today = Span of Time

Technically, when working with date-time values, a particular "date" is actually a span of time. The most common and generally useful way to define that span is "half-open" where the beginning is inclusive and the ending is exclusive. That means, for current date, we want the first moment of today (inclusive) to the first moment of tomorrow (exclusive). Then we ask if the target date-time falls within that span.

There are other ways to get this job done. I'm showing this approach because it is applies to situations beyond the question of "today".

## Joda-Time

Joda-Time offers three classes for defining a span of time: [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html), Period, and Duration.

### Example Code

Setup our input data, a Calendar object.

```
// Create a Calendar object to simulate input.
java.util.Date date = DateTime.now().minusDays( 3 ).toDate();
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime( date );
```

Define "today" as a span of time, and see if target date-time falls within that span.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime dateTimeInQuestion = new DateTime( cal.getTimeInMillis(), timeZone );
DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );

Interval today = new Interval( now.withTimeAtStartOfDay(), now.plusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay() );
boolean isDateTimeInQuestionInInterval = today.contains( dateTimeInQuestion );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "cal: " + cal.getTime() );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInQuestion: " + dateTimeInQuestion );
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "today: " + today );
System.out.println( "isDateTimeInQuestionInInterval: " + isDateTimeInQuestionInInterval );
```

When run…

```
cal: Wed Feb 12 22:46:04 PST 2014
dateTimeInQuestion: 2014-02-13T12:16:04.369+05:30
now: 2014-02-16T12:16:04.497+05:30
today: 2014-02-16T00:00:00.000+05:30/2014-02-17T00:00:00.000+05:30
isDateTimeInQuestionInInterval: false
```